# multiple markers shows in google map in php codeigniter

Tags: php

How to execute the php foreach loop in java script? i need to loop latitude_code & longitude_code in java script

this line should be in loop
var centerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitudes,longitudes);

please suggest me..

thanks for advance..

Answer (score 0):

in your view;

```
<script>
    // Your Java...

    <?php foreach($items as $item) { ?>
      google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $item->latitude; ?>,<?php echo $item->longitude; ?>);
    <?php } ?>

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Craig, Thanks for quick rply.. here i cant see the value by alert See take down the code as below                                             <?php foreach($items as $item){ ?>
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $item->latitude; ?>,<?php echo $item->longitude; ?>);
    <?php } ?>
 alert(myLatlng);

Answer (score 0):

Here's [demo]`(http://jsfiddle.net/2crQ7/)`,I think it will help you, in this example java script array is used and you are using php array.Just use your array for looping, don't pass location in **setMarkers(map,locations)** function .
Try with this example if you don't get answer I will provide my code.